# Can't find logon script Server Essentials 2012

Tags: windows-server-essentials, logon-scripts

Okay, I know I'm going to sound like an idiot, but I need help!  Years ago, I installed Home Server, then later upgraded to Server Essentials 2012.  On both of these setups, I have a logon script that redirects the"My Documents", "Pictures", etc & maps another network share "\\<server>\Software" to the "S: Drive".

This has been working for years, which is part of my problem.  I now need to change where the "S: Drive" points to, but I can't seem to find out where the script is that is setting it!

See, I sound dumb.

I've checked:
\\<server>\SYSVOL\<domain>\scripts and it's empty.
Default Domain Policy > User Configuration > Policies > Widows Settings > Scripts and this is blank as well.
The profiles tab for the individual users is also showing blank for logon script.

I also manually disconnected the mapped drive on one of my PC's.  When I reboot, it does come back.


I've just about run out of ideas on how to track down where this is getting set.

Comment: Usually folder redirection isn't done by scripts anymore but by group policys directly.

Answer (score 1):

Legacy logon scripts are stored in the NETLOGON shared folder (the folder you referenced in your question). Group Policy logon scripts are stored in the User\Scripts\Logon folder in the GPO folder for the GPO where the script is configured. Find the GPO where the script is configured and modify the script from the GPO or from it's GPO folder.

Example:

```
\\server\SYSVOL\AD.local\Policies\{2DA112B3-7945-46E2-936E-35F3CDCACCF0}\User\Scripts\Logon
```

Comment: I had 3 folders listed with GUID's & two of those contained the folder "User".  In the Scripts/Logon folder under there, there are no files (This folder is empty).